# NSGraphicsContext Perspective

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawrect

I'm drawing some shapes inside of a drawRect method.

**Note**: I am not using NSViews or Layers.

I am transforming my shapes points into 3d and then drawing them onto the screen....but they lack depth.

This is a screenshot of an rectangle drawn at a 45.0 rotation around the y axis...but it looks flat

[image: Screenshot]

Is there anyway I can set the NSGraphicsContext transform like:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500.0;
```

Or do I need to switch to using Open-GL?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question: why aren't you using layers? They use a lot of RAM but deliver a *massive* framerate boost for most situations.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, I'm not an expert, but CATransform is part of core animation which is a high level drawing framework. When you use `drawRect:` you are working directly with the graphics context, which is a low level drawing API (According to Apple's documentation it looks like Core Graphics (and therefore drawRect:) is talking direct to the GPU hardware, bypassing OpenGL). Therefore you're required to implement core animation yourself, if you want to use CATransform3D inside drawRect:.

But you can pick and choose just the parts of core animation you want, instead of using everything. For example you might create a CALayer object (or perhaps CAShapeLayer), apply the transform, and tell it to draw in the current context of your drawRect implementation.

Try to avoid creating layers inside drawRect:, since the drawRect: method should execute in a few thousands of a second if possible. You might create the layers the first time you draw, but subsequent draws should re-use ones created in a previous draw operation. Also if you get a low memory warning, you should throw all the layers away so they can be re-created next time you draw. Otherwise your app will likely be terminated in the background when it otherwise could have been left running, or perhaps even crash without any error message to the user while the app is in the foreground.

Or you could just avoid  drawRect: altogether, and go with core animation the whole way. That's what I do. If I need custom drawing I subclass CALayer.

Or you could use OpenGL if you want, which is what core animation will be doing anyway under the hood. It's a lot of code when you only want to do something basic though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could solve this problem by converting the 3D coordinates with an arbitrary z value of 0, to final screen coordinates by

> xyzw_coord = NDC * Projection matrix * View Matrix * Model Transform.

Build model transform with (0,0,0) being the center of the NSView.
Build view matrix with just rotation on Y. 
Build projection matrix with orthographic projection. 
NDC = [x,y,z,w]. with w = 1.

final_coord = (xy_coord.x/w * width, xy_coord.y/w * height).

The math is a lot of fun(read frustration) to implement. But its gratifying. But I do agree with Abhi, its better if you use core animation or better yet the new Apple SceneKit!